# WP_Query on function not showing pagination

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination

I have this code and its working fine, the only problem is that its not showing pagination. This code is on my functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );

function prefix_load_cat_posts () {
    global $post;
    $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args = array (
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    $cat_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($cat_query->have_posts()) :
        while($cat_query->have_posts()) : $cat_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
?>
    <div class="page-nation">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-large">
        <?php 
            $pagination = get_the_posts_pagination(array(
                'mid_size'  => 2,
                'prev_text' =>esc_html__('Previous', 'travel-tour'),
                'next_text' => esc_html__('Next', 'travel-tour'),
                'screen_reader_text' => ' ',
            ) );
            echo $pagination;
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div> 
<?php
    endif;
    die(); 
}
```

and this is my jquery ajax script

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery('.js-category-button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery('.preloadswitch').addClass('addpreloader');
  var catID = jQuery(this).data('slug');
  var catName =  jQuery(this).attr('href');
  var ajaxurl = '<?php echo esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ?>';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        crossDomain : true,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {"action": "load-filter", cat: catID },
        beforeSend: function () {
            jQuery(".the-categories").html('<div></div>').fadeIn('slow');
            jQuery(".page-nation").hide();
            //window.location.hash = "#"+jQuery("#comehere").attr("id");
            jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery('#comehere').offset().top}, 1000);
            window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', catName);
        },
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery(".the-categories").append(response);
            jQuery('.preloadswitch').removeClass('addpreloader');
            return false;
        }
    });
})

}); 

</script>
```

I don't what to do here anymore, I have been searching on the web for possible working function but with no luck.

I just need to show the pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out or remove the `wp_reset_query();`, or move it to after the pagination; and use [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) instead of [`get_the_posts_pagination()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/).

Here's the altered 'if-else' block in your `prefix_load_cat_posts()` function:

```
    if($cat_query->have_posts()) :
        while($cat_query->have_posts()) : $cat_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
        //wp_reset_query();
?>
    <div class="page-nation">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-large">
        <?php 
            $pagination = paginate_links(array(
                'mid_size'  => 2,
                'prev_text' =>esc_html__('Previous', 'travel-tour'),
                'next_text' => esc_html__('Next', 'travel-tour'),
                'current' => $paged,
                'total' => $cat_query->max_num_pages,
                'type' => 'array',
                'base' => home_url( '/%_%' ),
            ) );
            echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $pagination ) . '</li>';
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div> 
<?php
    endif;
```

[EDIT] Try setting the `base` parameter.

Comment: Hi @Sally CJ, I have change it to paginate_links() and its working but now the problem is the pagination link and its linking like this http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/page/3/

Comment: Hello, its showing the pagination links now but its not redirecting to its proper page, likes are from categories so path is changing every time it clicks a link.

Comment: Okay, I can help you fix that; but please share the HTML markup. And also, your question was already answered, right? I mean, *this* question: "*I just need to show the pagination*".

Comment: Never mind about the HTML markup. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49890303/9217760).